# Extension for Chrome to download specific files of specific types

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Is there an extension for Google Chrome that will let you download files of a specific types from the current webpage, and not require an external download manager?

So far I haven't found any, right now I use DownThemAll for Firefox just for that task.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know a specific extension for this, but you could adapt [Simple Get](https://code.google.com/p/simple-get/) for your purposes.

Simple Get is normally used to pass URLs to an *external* download manager, but nothing stops you from specifying Chrome itself as the download manager.

#### Configuration

1. [Download](http://www.chromeextensions.org/other/simple-get/) and install Simple Get.
2. Go to `chrome-extension://pgnbkflnoffangkfbmlfkdlmikmoilkj/options.html`.
3. In `Path`, enter the full name of the chrome executable.

   - `/usr/bin/google-chrome` on Ubuntu 12.04.
   - `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` on Windows 7, or something similar.
4. Set `Parameters` to `"[SG_URL]"`.
5. Leave `Destination` as it is.
6. Click `Save`.